# Similarity algorithm advice, using two dimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, similarity

The main goal of this algorithm is to find similar titles of news articles from different sources of web and group them, let's say above 55.55% similarity.

My current approach of the algorithm consist of following steps:

- Feed data from MYSQL database into a two-dimensional array ex. **$arrayOne**.
- Make another copy of that array into ex. **$arrayTwo**.
- Create a clean array which will only contain similar titles and other content ex. **$array_smlr**.
- Loop, foreach **$arrayOne** *article_title* check for similarity with **$arrayTwo**   *article_title*
- If similarity of between two titles is above 55% and if the article is not from the same news source (this way I don't check same articles from the same source) add it to **$array_smlr**
- Sort the **$array_smlr** based on percentages of similarity, this way I end up grouping titles that are similar.

Below is my code for the above tasks mentioned.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id_articles,article_img,article_title,LEFT(article_content , 200),psource, date_fetched FROM project.articles WHERE " . rtrim($values,' or') . " ORDER BY date_fetched DESC LIMIT 70");

$arrayOne=array();
$arrayTwo=array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arrayOne[] = $row;
}
$arrayTwo = $arrayOne;
$array_smlr=array();
foreach ($arrayOne as $rowOne) {
    foreach($arrayTwo as $rowTwo){
        $compare = similar_text($rowOne['article_title'], $rowTwo['article_title'], $p);
        if ( round($p,2) >= 55.50 and $rowOne['psource'] != $rowTwo['psource'] ){
            $data =  array('percentage' => round($p,2), 'article_title' => $rowTwo['article_title'], 'psource' => $rowTwo['psource'], 'id_articles' => $rowTwo['id_articles'], 'date_fetched' =>$rowTwo['date_fetched']);
            $array_smlr[]=$data; 
        }
    }
}
array_multisort($array_smlr);
foreach($array_smlr as $row3){
    echo $row3['percentage'] . $row3['article_title'] . $row3['psource'] . $row3['id_articles'] . $row3['date_fetched'] . "<br><br>";
}
```

This would work with limited functionality, only if I had two similar titles, but let's say if I had 3 similar titles, it would include duplicated rows of data in **$array_smlr**.

I would appreciate if you have any suggestions on optimization of this algorithm in order to improve the performance.

Thanks,

Comment: just use mysql's full text search: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need 2 arrays instead of the foreach loop without $key wildcard you can use it with $key and skip the solver when the $key is the same. Then you also avoid dupes.

```
foreach ($arrayOne as $key => $rowOne) {
   foreach($arrayOne as $ikey => $rowTwo){
      if ($ikey != $key) {
        $compare = similar_text($rowOne['article_title'],$rowTwo['article_title'], $p);
        if ( round($p,2) >= 55.50 and $rowOne['psource'] != $rowTwo['psource'] ){
            $data =  array('percentage' => round($p,2), 'article_title' => $rowTwo['article_title'], 'psource' => $rowTwo['psource'], 'id_articles' => $rowTwo['id_articles'], 'date_fetched' =>$rowTwo['date_fetched']);
            $array_smlr[$rowTwo['id_articles']]=$data; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain a little more on how to implement that? do i still use similar_text?

Comment: Yes, sure. If my answer is helfpul please consider to accept it and/or upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am getting this error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$key' (T_VARIABLE)  

I even tried fixing that error by changin $arrayOne $key => $rowOn and $arrayOne $ikey => $rowTwo but it won't return anything.

Comment: How come that I am still getting dupes, and that is only happening when if there are three similar titles, not when there are two titles?

Comment: Add Group by article_title to your MySQL clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78193/discussion-between-comsci-dude-and-phpdevpad).

Comment: still the same issue, for some reason whenever there is a third similar title it will include duplicates too! 

I tried to remove duplicates from the array, but i was unable to do so! Maybe you have any idea?

Comment: Try an associative array like so:$array_smlr[$key]=$data;

Comment: finally i think we got it to work not to have duplicates when there are more than one title. Thank you man for your patience and help!! You think you know a way how to group them with a special ID the ones which are similar that way when I show them I can group them the ones which are similar. 

Ex. AAAAAA 1 
AAAABA 1
KKKKL 2
KKKKK 2