# Only unique elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, similarity

There is a feed from which I receive data, and sometimes very similar records appear in it.
https://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2020/01/17/0028/2950/1842054/54/5abb738180.jpg

I want to make sure that the array contains the most unique records. (Define by title)

Code:

```
$new = array();
$goodFeed = array();

$itemlimit=0;
$itemlimit2=0;


foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    if ($itemlimit==50) { break; };
    $new[] = strtolower(trim($item->get_title()));
    $itemlimit = $itemlimit + 1;
}

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    if ($itemlimit2==50) { break; };
    $itemTitle = strtolower(trim($item->get_title()));

    foreach($new as $item2) {
        similar_text($item2, $itemTitle, $percent);

        if ($percent < 78 && !in_array($item, $goodFeed)) {
                $goodFeed[] = $item;
                echo 'added: ' . $item->get_title() . '<br>Procent: ' . $percent . '<hr>';

        }
    }

    $itemlimit2 = $itemlimit2 + 1;
}
```

I want only unique values (min 80%) to remain in $goodFeed array. Now it contains elements that are very similar to each other.
The original feed has elements with names:

```
1. Metro Redux on Nintendo Switch™ Announce Trailer; 
2. Metro Redux on Nintendo Switch™ Announce Trailer [NA]; 
3. Metro Redux für Nintendo Switch™ Ankündigungs-Trailer [DE]; 
4. Metro Redux on Nintendo Switch™ Announce Trailer [ANZ]; 
5. The Elder Scrolls Online: The Dark Heart of Skyrim Announcement Cinematic;
6. The Elder Scrolls Online - The Dark Heart of Skyrim Cinematic Announcement Trailer
```

They all go into $goodFeed, I want only these:

```
1. Metro Redux on Nintendo Switch™ Announce Trailer
5. The Elder Scrolls Online: The Dark Heart of Skyrim Announcement Cinematic
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what your code is doing that is not doing what you want it to do?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I want only unique values (min 80%) to remain in $goodFeed array. Now it contains elements that are very similar to each other.

The original fida has elements with names:
1. Metro Redux on Nintendo Switch™ Announce Trailer; 
2. Metro Redux für Nintendo Switch™ Ankündigungs-Trailer [DE]; 
3. Metro Redux on Nintendo Switch™ Announce Trailer [ANZ]; 
4. The Elder Scrolls Online: The Dark Heart of Skyrim Announcement Cinematic;
5. The Elder Scrolls Online - The Dark Heart of Skyrim Cinematic Announcement Trailer

They all go into $goodFeed, I want only these: 1 and 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the parser wasn't transmitting the correct feed. Recycled the array structure and now it's working. I also took ideas from here - [Similarity algorithm advice, using two dimensional associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312819/similarity-algorithm-advice-using-two-dimensional-associative-array)

If someone knows a good and still supported RSS parser (NodeJs, Php) that can combine feeds into one, I would appreciate it if you could link to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have not tested but I think one of these should work for you.

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) { 
    if(!strtolower(trim($item->get_title())),$new){
        if ($itemlimit==50) { break; };
        $new[] = strtolower(trim($item->get_title()));
        $goodFeed[] = $item;
        $itemlimit = $itemlimit + 1;
    }
}

-------OR-------

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) { 
    if(!strtolower(trim($item->get_title())),$new){
        if(count($new)>0){
            $percent=0;
            foreach($new as $n){
                similar_text($n, strtolower(trim($item->get_title())), $percent);
                if($percent>78){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($percent>78){
                    continue;
            }

            if ($itemlimit==50) { break; };
            $new[] = strtolower(trim($item->get_title()));
            $goodFeed[] = $item;
            $itemlimit = $itemlimit + 1;
        }
        else{
            $new[] = strtolower(trim($item->get_title()));
            $goodFeed[] = $item;
            $itemlimit = $itemlimit + 1;
        }
    }
}
```